# Stripe elements with magnetic card reader javascript issue

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am migrating from stripe js v2 to stripe js v3. And in v3 js it is recommended to use stripe elements for payment form. But in v2, I was collecting card information using Magnetic card reader and for that reason I was using the javascript below in the link.

https://blog.kiosksimple.com/2017/06/22/parse-credit-card-data-javascript/

But in v3 I won't be able to populate the data read from magnetic card reader in stripe elements like card number and card expiry date. If I try to set `cardNumber` using the update method mentioned in:

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#other-methods.

It gave me **Uncaught IntegrationError: Sensitive data (`cardNumber`) cannot be filled in.**
I am stuck at this point how can I use stripe elements with magnetic card reader? Is there any way for me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Elements, you can not pre-fill the card number yourself. This is not supported to ensure that you can't access the card details and meet the easiest requirements for PCI compliance. You can find more details about this here: https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance

What I would recommend here is looking into [Terminal](https://stripe.com/terminal), which is Stripe's point of sale product. You would be able to get a reader from them and accept in-person payments easily.

Comment: This is frustrating. I have the same issue. I think stripe should handle the keyboard input from a magnetic card reader for us. Then we could just focus on the input and have the user swipe their card. At the moment, this makes a mess of the form.